# expo run:android failed gradle

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, expo

I'm trying to run my React-Native (Expo) app on Android device.
First of all i ran an `expo prebuild` command,
[and i got this traceback](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GYgSf.png)

ok, i did not attach much importance to the error
and after that i ran `expo run:android`

and i got this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Settings file '/Desktop/projects/'[PROJECT NAME]'/android/settings.gradle' line: 6

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating settings '[PROJECT NAME]'.
> String index out of range: 0

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 770ms
/Desktop/projects/'[PROJECT NAME]'/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
Error: /Desktop/projects/'[PROJECT NAME]'/android/gradlew exited with non-zero code: 1
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:65:13)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:642:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/src/spawnAsync.ts:26:19)
    at spawnGradleAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/spawnGradleAsync.ts:83:18)
    at assembleAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/spawnGradleAsync.ts:57:16)
    at actionAsync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/expo-cli/src/commands/run/android/runAndroid.ts:143:9)
```

this is my `setting.gradle` file:

```
rootProject.name = '[PROJECT NAME]'

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../scripts/autolinking.gradle");
useExpoModules()

apply from: new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../native_modules.gradle");
applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)

include ':app'
```

What have I done wrong?
Please help me understand

Answer (score 0):

```
expo doctor
expo doctor --fix-dependencies
```

These commands solved my errors and i was able to build my app

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).